# Landline on NBN reverts phone's +8 WA, AU time to UTC time on any incoming call

Tags: internet-connection, date-time, fiber

I have a very, very strange issue to report and I have zero idea why it's happening. I can't even be sure if it's NBN-related or what could be causing this.

An older lady friend has NBN FTTP. She has a priority landline, meaning her phone plugs directly to the battery-backed-up NBN V-port. She started having connection issues and rang Telstra to check it for her. They said there wasn't anything wrong as far as they could tell.

Here's what's happening now and it's a weird one: the phone set includes one base station + one satellite. When you set the time on the base, it also sets it to the satellite. So, you set our current time (+8 , WA). All fine. It will keep time perfectly, – until any incoming call is answered, where the time will change and go back exactly 8 hours (UTC?) !!!

This has been replicated now on four, different phones (three new from Telstra, one from me). The only thing I could think of was that maybe it's something to do with the NBN box since that's where the phone plugs to? I tried a reset + power-off of the NBN box (but didn't disconnect the b-backup as the cord was stuck tight in the NBN box and I didn't feel comfortable trying to get that stupid battery out). Three technicians from Telstra have attended and no one can fix it.

Any ideas what could be causing this? I'm completely stumped.

Thanks all!

Comment: It may not be obvious to many people here - NBN is the consumer broadband in Australia. AFAIK its called fibre but its more often delivered as VDSL.

Comment: Have you tried another Telecom? Relates do not exactly exude confidence and there are plenty of other providers. My guess is an issue on the Telecom side (if multiple technicians have looked).

Comment: (Its not liklely to be a fibre or DSL issue. It could conceivably be related to your NTP settings in the router, but from the description it sounds more like issues with the SIP packets being sent from the VOIP server

Comment: Thinking about this a bbit more - your NBN box most likely has an ntp client in it, but also a timezone - if the timezone is set incorrectly I bet that is the problem.  Not being in Ozzie though, I've no idea if Helstra provision this or if its something you can do. (What is the model of the device the phones plug into?)

Comment: I reckon the last comment from @davidgo is likely on the money (was "Helstra" tongue in cheek or a typo? 8-P) - and definitely posting the make/models of your devices would help others greatly. But, if you don't have any luck here, I'd suggest try asking over at Whirpool Forums (https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/) - it's long been a bastion of discussing Aussie ISP related issues.

Comment: @user1138 Good call re whirlpool forums.  I make plenty of typos as most of the stuff I type is from my cellphone.   I've also had the misfortune of dealing with that company - luckily not on my own dime.  Muscle memory perhaps?

Comment: Helstra is a total f*up. I just want to know who to blame so I can go after the proper entity. Yes, Telstra is the ISP, and yes, Telstra runs the modem (for Internet). However, her phone line is direct from the NBN fiber connection port. Can someone please give me some ammo on how to get Telstra to own-up/fix this issue? What diags can I run to print-screen/save, etc... to prove the trouble? Modem is the Telstra Smart Modem v2. 

26 apr 2022  Still no answer! Okay. This is seriously not THAT hard, is it????
Can anyone solve this ?

Comment: Have you checked this is set to the correct TZ: Page 40, Modem Time Settings - https://www.letsbemates.com.au/mate/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Telstra-Smart-Modem-Gen-2-LH1000-User-Manual.pdf